# Handling jQuery deferred.done being called even though request is aborted?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a function that makes a http call to a web service, grabs some data and calls another function based on this data. If the service is down, the second function should not be called. I thought the obvious way to do this would be to write `$.when(func1()).done(func2);` but this will trigger func2 even when the request is aborted. I realise that I can do a workaround by calling func2 within the success function of func1's `$.getJSON` method, but I would like to use the deferred syntax if possible. Can anyone suggest how to handle this in a way that is consistent with the deferred object syntax?

```
function checker() {
    console.log("in checker");
    $.getJSON("http://djdjdjdjdjinvalidUrl.dkdkdk", function(data) {
        console.log("in success function");
    });
} 

function crosser(data) {
    console.log("in crosser");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.when(checker()).done(crosser);
});
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wM7aP/) for a live example.

Comment: That isn't what `$.when` is for. Just use `checker().done(crosser)`. `$.when` is for creating a new promise which wraps around *multiple* promises.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you need to return a promise from `checker`

```
function checker() {
    console.log("in checker");
    return $.getJSON("http://djdjdjdjdjinvalidUrl.dkdkdk", function(data) {
        console.log("in success function");
    });
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UuYmj/)

Also there is no need to use `$.when()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    checker().done(crosser);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mdj5k/)

Comment: @A.Wolff may the OP got interested in the complexity of the other answer

Comment: Anyway, the other answer should not be used in any case as stipuled by Bergi in comment

Comment: sorry, I thought I could mark both as correct. So I marked Arun's as correct but also Zathrus' which then unmarked Arun's. My bad.

Comment: @ronan_mac you can only mark one answer correct but can +1 both of them if you like

Answer (score 0):

For asynchronous events like `$.getJSON`, you need to use the actual [**deferred object**](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). I've updated your jsfiddle with this object in use: http://jsfiddle.net/wM7aP/1/

Code:

```
function checker() {
    var dfd = new jQuery.Deferred();
    console.log("in checker");
    $.getJSON("http://djdjdjdjdjinvalidUrl.dkdkdk", function(data) {
        //handle data here
        dfd.resolve( "hurray" );
    });
    return dfd.promise();
} 

function crosser(data) {
    console.log("in crosser");
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.when(checker()).done(crosser);
});
```

Comment: I guess this is an alternative to Arun's answer, should you need to create more complex structures in the future :)

Comment: Thanks! What is the advantage of initialising a deferred object and returning `dfd.promise`over simply returning the ´$.getJSON`as [Arun P Johny does](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18741807/1031478)?

Comment: @ronan_mac: None, and that's the reason why you should not use this. It especially doesn't work when your request fails (or is aborted), as the promise will never be resolved then.

Comment: @Bergi none of our 2 solutions actually resolve when the script fails to load for that matter, so I guess your reasoning is not quite valid here? Or maybe I'm just missing something...

Comment: Sorry for the confusing vocabulary, but the term "resolution" ("resolve") is used for both fulfilling and rejecting a promise. You forgot to reject it in case.

Comment: @Bergi ok, so you mean just rejecting the deferred not handling that reject case then? because otherwise both our codes produce identical result. I think I get what you mean now, thanks :)